# "Ну" как слово-предложение

Tags: синтаксис

(Что-то больно много вопросов у меня в последнее время появляется...) Задали мне тут в моем учебном заведении выписать из текста слова-предложения, и я сомневаюсь: является частица (междометие?) "ну" в данном контексте словом-предложением или нет. (Или, быть может, "ну" всегда является словом-предложением?) Текст: *"Почему, скажи, у тебя Анатоль, а не Анатолий? Если бы ты меня написал Анатоль, я..." - "Что ты?" - "Не стерпел бы..." -"**Ну**, а как... Анатолю Франсу?" - "Кто это?" - "Великий француз не стыдился и не боялся, что он Анатоль". - "Гм..." - "**Ну**, а Велюгин... а Вертинский, а Гречаников... а Клышко".*

Не поможете?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном тексте междометие "ну", скорее всего, предложением  не является. В этом случае можно сказать, что "модальная функция междометия реализуется в условиях вводности" (Грамматика-80).

НУ будет является словом-предложением, если оно оформлено как отдельное предложение, например:  "Ты что, болен? - Ну". "Сегодня он уезжает.  - Ну?!"

Или в составе СПП в качестве придаточного предложения:"Сыграл такого дурака, что ну!"

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо!)